# How to draw different shapes with Python using Graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz

I tried to draw structure graph with Python. Nodes are like this

[image: 1].

Since I also need to use different shape of arrows. So I wanted to use Graphviz to implement this. Is there any method to draw like this?

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually asking based on the information provided. The image shown can be made in MS paint.

Answer (score 0):

Many people seem to use PyPl (https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/) to interface Python to Graphviz.  Read all the installation instructions & remember to install the actual Graphviz system.
There are two ways to build node structures, I recommend HTML-like nodes (https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) (a bit wordy, but fewer layout restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

There are few options to interface Graphviz with python:

- graphviz
- pygraphviz
- graphviz-python
- pydot

---

You can use Records-based Nodes or HTML-based Nodes to get the intended result:

```py
import graphviz

g = graphviz.Digraph('G')

g.node('n1', '{name|{a|b|c}}',
       shape='record',
       fillcolor='skyblue',
       style='filled')

g.view()
```

[image: sample_record]